# How to read from a file but each line is read into different variables or functions?

Tags: c++

I have to read from this text file. I need to read the first line into an integer and the second line into doubly linked list that I have defined as a C++ class. Then, for the 3rd line until the -1, I need to read those into another class defined array list. Basically my question is how do I read from the file per line while also choosing where they go to?

I've gotten as far as:

```
ifstream inData;
inData.open("inputfile.txt");
if (!inData) {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
    return; 
}
inData >> sr;
while (inData >> data)
{
    //something happens here
}
```

but after that, I don't know how to specify from which line to change the destination or where the values read are supposed to go. And with a while loop the entire file will be read, which I don't want.

0 // initial state

B 0 0 0 0 B // initial cell values on tape

0 0 0 0 R // move right

0 1 0 1 R // move right

0 B 1 B L // when a blank at the right is found, change to state 1 and move left

1 0 0 1 R // if a 0 is changed to 1, change to state 0 and move right

1 1 1 0 L // if a 1 is changed to 0, move left

1 B 0 1 H // if a B is changed to 1, stop

-1 // end of the action table

6 // initial position of read/write pointer

note: the length of the file and the line is arbitrary.

Comment: Hint:  You can pass the file stream to functions.  Hint 2:  `std::getline`.  Hint 3:  `std::string`.

Comment: you've not really understood the question at all